# Less than function in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I've come across 2 confusing problems in SML and was hoping someone could help me out:

The first is a function which takes an element and a list and decides whether that element exists in the list or not, here is the code I've attempted to write:

```
fun member (e,L) = foldl (fn(a,b) => if (e = b) then true else false) false L;
```

But I get bool * 'a list --> bool   but what I need is ''a * ''a list --> bool

As for the second, it also requires an element and a list but returns a list of elements less than the passed one. I'm not sure whether this should be done via map or foldr/foldl.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Note that `if (e = b) then true else false` is just a complicated way of saying `e = b` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the first question, in `fn (a, b) => ...` `a` is the next element and `b` is the accumulator. Since you compare `e` with `b`, e is infered to have type `bool`. You should compare `e` with `a`, and never override `b` when it becomes `true`:

```
fun exists (e, L) =
    foldl (fn (a, b) => e = a orelse b) false L
```

For the second question, you can use `foldr/foldl` to do so. It's similar to the first example; you start with empty list as the accumulator and prepend an element to it whenever that element is smaller than a threshold.

As a tradeoff, `foldr` gives you the right order but it isn't tail-recursive. On the other hand, `foldl` is tail-recursive but gives resulting lists in a reverse order.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I managed to solve the second problem using foldl as well

Comment: And `if e = a then true else b` can be abbreviated to `e = a orelse b`. ;)

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: Thanks, I updated the answer after your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

to see if an element is in list or not try this:
fun elementExist(e, nil) = false
| elementExist(e, x::xs) = if e = x orelse elementExist(e, xs) then true else false;

for the second one to remove the existing element from the list:

fun elFromList(e, nil) = []
| elFromList(e, x::xs) = if e = x then elFromList(e, xs) else x::elFromList(e, xs);

Good Luck!!